# Percentage Change values for Prices in a given basked: Gemoetric mean vs arithmetic mean to get "mean" Prices

Tags: mean, geometric-mean

Lets say i have a Timeseries of data for different goods in a basked.
Af first, i do not want to calculate an index value to answer the question "How much more expensive is the basked compared to a reference period". The reason is that the prices in this basked are on vastly different scales.
Instead i first want to calculate the percentage change values between successors of each belonging value (in time).

Than i want to calculate the "average" percentage change at a given Point in time. So i want to now how much on average the prices changed between periods. Would i need to use the geometric or arithmetic mean?
I do know that for the compound percentage change over time i would use the geometric mean. But i am calculating the values at a specific point in time.

Is there a better way to answer this question?

Example:

| good | this wekk price | last week price | pct_change |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| good_1 | 4 | 5 | -0.2 |
| good_2 | 1 | 10 | -0.9 |

Would the aritmetric mean of -0.55 descirbe the "average"percentage change better than the geometirc mean of  -0.4242in this case?
Does this depend on the distribution of the Price values? How to deal with the fact that an negative numbers can not be treated ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

We would use the geometric mean if it was the same good declining by different prices throughout time (which would be appropriate for averaging growth/decline rates for the same thing), but you have different goods.

I think you want to know how a basket of goods has declined in price as a whole—so for that, I would actually just sum the previous week prices across all goods, and sum the current week prices across all goods, and calculate the percent change of that. So it would be $(15-5)/15=.67$ decline. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. But what if the data does not obey normaity? Some very large values dominate your caculation if you do it like this. This is why i calculate the individual percentage changes first. I gues i could always rescale the decimal percentage change values r = (V2-V1)/V2 like this to calculate the geometric mean nth_sqrt((1+r_i) x (1+r_i-1) x ....)-1. That way the negative values would be treated. I am just very unsure how to procede. I am not interested in the average change of the whole basked. I am interested in the average rate of change within the basked.

Answer (score 0):

I think it makes sense to look at the *differences* rather than summarize the *Before* basket and the *After* basket.  In a way, this is the same logic as a paired *t*-test or a paired Wilcoxon signed rank test.

In your case, because the values range quite a bit, looking at the percent change for each pair *may* make sense.

This isn't my field, but my supposition is that any measure that works to express what you want to express is helpful.  If the data (percent changes) are log-normally distributed, the geometric mean would make sense.  If the distribution is relatively symmetric, the mean may make sense.  In other cases, the median or a different measure of central tendency may make sense.

For better advice, it may be helpful if you present histograms or summaries of a representative piece of your *Before*, *After*, *Difference*, and *Percent change*.